# Problem in running boost eample blocking_udp_echo_client on MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I am trying to run blocking_udp_echo_client on MacOS X
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_udp_echo_client.cpp

I run it with argument 'localhost 9000'

But the program crashes and this is the line  in the source which crashes:
`udp::socket s(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 0));'

this is the stack trace:

```
    #0      0x918c3e42 in __kill
#1      0x918c3e34 in kill$UNIX2003
#2      0x9193623a in raise
#3      0x91942679 in abort
#4      0x940d96f9 in __gnu_debug::_Error_formatter::_M_error
#5      0x0000e76e in
__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator::op_base*> >,
__gnu_debug_def::list::op_base*>,
std::allocator::op_base*> > >
>::_Safe_iterator at safe_iterator.h:124
#6      0x00014729 in boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::bucket_type::bucket_type
at hash_map.hpp:277
#7      0x00019e97 in std::_Construct::op_base*>::bucket_type,
boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::bucket_type> at
stl_construct.h:81
#8      0x0001a457 in
std::__uninitialized_fill_n_aux::op_base*>::bucket_type*,
__gnu_norm::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type> >
>, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::bucket_type> at
stl_uninitialized.h:194
#9      0x0001a4e1 in
std::uninitialized_fill_n::op_base*>::bucket_type*,
__gnu_norm::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type> >
>, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::bucket_type> at
stl_uninitialized.h:218
#10     0x0001a509 in
std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a::op_base*>::bucket_type*,
__gnu_norm::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type> >
>, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::bucket_type,
boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::bucket_type> at
stl_uninitialized.h:310
#11     0x0001aa34 in
__gnu_norm::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::_M_fill_insert at vector.tcc:365
#12     0x0001acda in
__gnu_norm::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::insert at stl_vector.h:658
#13     0x0001ad81 in
__gnu_norm::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::resize at stl_vector.h:427
#14     0x0001ae3a in
__gnu_debug_def::vector::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::resize at vector:169
#15     0x0001b7be in boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::rehash at
hash_map.hpp:221
#16     0x0001bbeb in boost::asio::detail::hash_map::op_base*>::hash_map at
hash_map.hpp:67
#17     0x0001bc74 in
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue::reactor_op_queue at
reactor_op_queue.hpp:42
#18     0x0001bd24 in
boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::kqueue_reactor at
kqueue_reactor.hpp:86
#19     0x0001c000 in
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service
> at service_registry.hpp:109
#20     0x0001c14d in
boost::asio::use_service >
at io_service.ipp:195
#21     0x0001c26d in
boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service >::reactive_socket_service
at reactive_socket_service.hpp:111
#22     0x0001c344 in
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service > > at
service_registry.hpp:109
#23     0x0001c491 in
boost::asio::use_service > > at io_service.ipp:195
#24     0x0001c4d5 in
boost::asio::datagram_socket_service::datagram_socket_service
at datagram_socket_service.hpp:95
#25     0x0001c59e in
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service
> at service_registry.hpp:109
#26     0x0001c6eb in
boost::asio::use_service
> at io_service.ipp:195
#27     0x0001c711 in
boost::asio::basic_io_object
>::basic_io_object at basic_io_object.hpp:72
#28     0x0001c783 in boost::asio::basic_socket
>::basic_socket at basic_socket.hpp:108
#29     0x0001c865 in
boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket
>::basic_datagram_socket at basic_datagram_socket.hpp:107
#30     0x000027bc in main at main.cpp:32
```

This is the gdb output:

```
(gdb) continue
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/debug/safe_iterator.h:127:
   error: attempt to copy-construct an iterator from a singular iterator.

Objects involved in the operation:
iterator "this" @ 0x0x100420 {
type = N11__gnu_debug14_Safe_iteratorIN10__gnu_norm14_List_iteratorISt4pairIiPN5boost4asio6detail16reactor_op_queueIiE7op_baseEEEEN15__gnu_debug_def4listISB_SaISB_EEEEE
(mutable iterator);
 state = singular;
}
iterator "other" @ 0x0xbfffe8a4 {
type = N11__gnu_debug14_Safe_iteratorIN10__gnu_norm14_List_iteratorISt4pairIiPN5boost4asio6detail16reactor_op_queueIiE7op_baseEEEEN15__gnu_debug_def4listISB_SaISB_EEEEE
(mutable iterator);
 state = singular;
}
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb) continue
Program received signal:  “?”.
```

Does someone has any idea why this example does not work on mac osx?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the boost::asio library. [Here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3098) is the corresponding bug report.