# boost asio example crashes on mac osx

Tags: c++, boost, macos, boost-asio

I am trying to run  blocking_udp_echo_server.cpp from Boost asio example on MacOSX 10.5.

But it crashes:

```
From the console:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.0.0/debug/safe_iterator.h:127:
   error: attempt to copy-construct an iterator from a singular iterator.

Objects involved in the operation:
iterator "this" @ 0x0x100420 {
type = N11__gnu_debug14_Safe_iteratorIN10__gnu_norm14_List_iteratorISt4pairIiPN5boost4asio6detail16reactor_op_queueIiE7op_baseEEEEN15__gnu_debug_def4listISB_SaISB_EEEEE
(mutable iterator);
 state = singular;
}
iterator "other" @ 0x0xbfffee64 {
type = N11__gnu_debug14_Safe_iteratorIN10__gnu_norm14_List_iteratorISt4pairIiPN5boost4asio6detail16reactor_op_queueIiE7op_baseEEEEN15__gnu_debug_def4listISB_SaISB_EEEEE
(mutable iterator);
 state = singular;
}
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

From backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x918c3e42 in __kill ()
#1  0x918c3e34 in kill$UNIX2003 ()
#2  0x9193623a in raise ()
#3  0x91942679 in abort ()
#4  0x940d96f9 in __gnu_debug::_Error_formatter::_M_error ()
#5  0x0000ada6 in
__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_norm::_List_iterator<std::pair<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*> >,
__gnu_debug_def::list<std::pair<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>,
std::allocator<std::pair<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*> > >
>::_Safe_iterator (this=0x100420, __x=@0xbfffee64) at
debug/safe_iterator.h:124
#6  0x00010195 in boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type::bucket_type
(this=0x100420) at hash_map.hpp:277
#7  0x0001291d in std::_Construct<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
(__p=0x100420, __value=@0xbfffee64) at stl_construct.h:81
#8  0x00012edd in
std::__uninitialized_fill_n_aux<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type*,
__gnu_norm::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type> >
>, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
(__first={_M_current = 0x100420}, __n=3, __x=@0xbfffee64) at
stl_uninitialized.h:194
#9  0x00012f67 in
std::uninitialized_fill_n<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type*,
__gnu_norm::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type> >
>, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
(__first={_M_current = 0x100420}, __n=3, __x=@0xbfffee64) at
stl_uninitialized.h:218
#10 0x00012f8f in
std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type*,
__gnu_norm::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type> >
>, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
(__first={_M_current = 0x100420}, __n=3, __x=@0xbfffee64) at
stl_uninitialized.h:310
#11 0x000134ba in
__gnu_norm::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::_M_fill_insert (this=0x1002f0, __position={_M_current = 0x0},
__n=3, __x=@0xbfffee64) at vector.tcc:365
#12 0x00013760 in
__gnu_norm::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::insert (this=0x1002f0, __position={_M_current = 0x0}, __n=3,
__x=@0xbfffee64) at stl_vector.h:658
#13 0x00013807 in
__gnu_norm::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::resize (this=0x1002f0, __new_size=3, __x=@0xbfffee64) at
stl_vector.h:427
#14 0x000138c0 in
__gnu_debug_def::vector<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type,
std::allocator<boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::bucket_type>
>::resize (this=0x1002f0, __sz=3, __c=@0xbfffee64) at debug/vector:169
#15 0x0001400e in boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::rehash
(this=0x1002c4, num_buckets=3) at hash_map.hpp:221
#16 0x0001443b in boost::asio::detail::hash_map<int,
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::op_base*>::hash_map
(this=0x1002c4) at hash_map.hpp:67
#17 0x000144c4 in
boost::asio::detail::reactor_op_queue<int>::reactor_op_queue
(this=0x1002c0) at reactor_op_queue.hpp:42
#18 0x00014574 in
boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor<false>::kqueue_reactor
(this=0x100270, io_service=@0xbffff7a4) at kqueue_reactor.hpp:86
#19 0x00014850 in
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor<false>
> (this=0x100180) at service_registry.hpp:109
#20 0x0001499d in
boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor<false> >
(ios=@0xbffff7a4) at impl/io_service.ipp:195
#21 0x00014abd in
boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp,
boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor<false> >::reactive_socket_service
(this=0x100250, io_service=@0xbffff7a4) at
reactive_socket_service.hpp:111
#22 0x00014b94 in
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp,
boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor<false> > > (this=0x100180) at
service_registry.hpp:109
#23 0x00014ce1 in
boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp,
boost::asio::detail::kqueue_reactor<false> > > (ios=@0xbffff7a4) at
impl/io_service.ipp:195
#24 0x00014d25 in
boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>::datagram_socket_service
(this=0x100230, io_service=@0xbffff7a4) at
datagram_socket_service.hpp:95
#25 0x00014dee in
boost::asio::detail::service_registry::use_service<boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>
> (this=0x100180) at service_registry.hpp:109
#26 0x00014f3b in
boost::asio::use_service<boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>
> (ios=@0xbffff7a4) at impl/io_service.ipp:195
#27 0x00014f61 in
boost::asio::basic_io_object<boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>
>::basic_io_object (this=0xbffff6a4, io_service=@0xbffff7a4) at
basic_io_object.hpp:72
#28 0x00014fd3 in boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp,
boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>
>::basic_socket (this=0xbffff6a4, io_service=@0xbffff7a4,
endpoint=@0xbffff6b8) at basic_socket.hpp:108
#29 0x000150b5 in
boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket<boost::asio::ip::udp,
boost::asio::datagram_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::udp>
>::basic_datagram_socket (this=0xbffff6a4, io_service=@0xbffff7a4,
endpoint=@0xbffff6b8) at basic_datagram_socket.hpp:107
#30 0x00002022 in server (io_service=@0xbffff7a4, port=8090) at
/Users/n179911/Documents/ServerXCode/main.cpp:21
#31 0x0000217a in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff7e8) at
/Users/n179911/Documents/ServerXCode/main.cpp:47
(gdb)
```

Any one has any idea?

Comment: What compiler options? what optimization level?

Comment: I use XCode to compile the code. I am using the default compiler options and optimization level.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183270/problem-in-running-boost-eample-blocking-udp-echo-client-on-macosx. See my answer on that question. It was a known bug in boost::asio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand the only guaranteed operation on a singluar value is assigning a nonsigular one. Since i think the lib code is ok i get the impression your problem is more related to the build process:

I would try the following approach to pinpoint the probem furhter:

1. Using heavy optimization sometimes leads to problems, in rare cases default optimization might as well. Remove all optimization.
2. If you build boost with an other compiler as your code that might lead to problems. If you didn't build it by yourself with the same compiler try it. Might be it even won't build.
3. Using the first compiler revision (4.0.0, 3.0.0 etc..) might be a problem as well since those are mostly buggy (at least in case of GNU cc). Try 4.1 or something.